# Exclude last characters from regex pattern

Tags: regex, partial-matches

How do i extract this from a regex:

`mymatch[ someother char ]`

What i want is `mymatch` when followed by a `[` but i don't want the square bracket in the match.

I'm stuck on this but it gets also the square bracket:

`\b.*?\[`

*More in general, how can i exclude from the match some portion of the pattern?*

For example here `(abc2)mymatch` i want a regex returning my match only when it is preeceds by `(abc2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this you need to use **lookahead** and **lookbehind** , in first one use **positive lookahead** :

```
\w+(?=\[)
```

> ?=[ : mean followed by "[" and not catch in matches

in second example use **positive lookbehind** :

```
(?<=\(abc2\))\w+
```

> (?<=(abc2)) : mean leaded by "(abc2)" and not catch in matches

[for more information about lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: It works great, @aziz